# Reduction formula for $\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^m\theta\sin^n\theta\,d\theta$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, integration-by-parts

I have done the first section, but am totally stuck on how to proceed on (b).

[image: Screenshot of problem here]

Comment: See [Wallis' integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis'_integrals), especially the paragraph about their connection to [Euler's beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align}J(m,n) =\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} cos^m\theta sin^n\theta d\theta \\
J(m,n) =\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} cos^{(m-1)}\theta sin^n\theta cos\theta d\theta\\
\end{align}

Then solve by parts where $sin^n\theta cos\theta = \frac{du}{dx}$ and in that integral substitute $u' = sin\theta$

\begin{align}
\int u'^n \frac{du'}{dx} dx = \int u'^n du' = \frac{sin^{n+1}\theta}{n+1} + C
\end{align}

And so:

\begin{align}
J(m,n) &= \left[\frac{cos^{m-1}\theta sin^{n+1}\theta}{n+1}\right]_0^\frac{\pi}{2} - \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{(m-1)cos^{(m-2)}\theta (-sin\theta)sin^{(n+1)}}{n+1} d\theta \\
&= 0 + \frac{m-1}{n+1} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} cos^{m-2}\theta(1-cos^2\theta)sin^n\theta d\theta\\
&= \frac{m-1}{n+1}J(m-2,n)-\frac{m-1}{n+1}J(m,n)\\
&=\frac{m-1}{n+m}J(m-2,n)
\end{align}

Hope that helps

Comment: It might be good to expand the jump between the last two lines.

Answer (score 0):

Try both ways. Write $$\sin(x) = -d(\cos(x))$$
and $$\cos(x) = d(\sin(x) )$$
Then integrate by parts!